# Irony and lack of self-awareness

Tags: irony

They are not the same, are they? For example, if a person says: "I can't stand those f----ng people because they are so foul-mouthed!", I don't view the statement as ironic. But some highly-educated friends disagree with me.

Comment: What arguments have they given for them being the same? (And why do you say they aren't?)

Comment: How is irony defined? Why would one think it is or is not ironic? What has "self-awareness" to do with the question? What *is* the question?

Comment: The OP I think is asking whether the example sentence constitutes irony or simple cluelessness. I think a different way to ask for clarification might be, "I am not clear on whether you are asking about a definition of irony, or what, about the sentence, is or is not ironic. Could you please give some additional details or explanation so I can understand what you are after? I will check back. Thanks."

Comment: In my opinion, it can be a form of irony if the speaker does this intentionally, and/or if it appears in a book and the author did it intentionally. If there is no underlying point or conclusion being drawn, then it is only hypocritical, not ironic.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is common to use "ironic" in a blanket manner for a number of situations in which something is in opposition to the words being used, after looking at several definitions for ironic, I think that in the example you used, hypocrisy more closely describes the situation.

[hypocrisy](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/hypocrisy?s=t)

from dictionary.com

noun, plural hy·poc·ri·sies

1. a pretense of having a virtuous character, moral or religious beliefs or principles, etc., that one does not really possess.
2. a pretense of having some desirable or publicly approved attitude.
3. an act or instance of hypocrisy.

The first meaning above implies the lack of awareness that I sense in your question and example, "I can't stand those f----ng people because they are so foul-mouthed!"

Hypocritical also encompasses the tone of moral superiority in the sentence.

Certainly, the speaker sounds oblivious to the contradiction. 
(Does hypocrisy *require* one's ignorance or lack of self-awareness? Anyone want to weigh in on whether hypocrisy exists in particular oblivion? I want to move on to *irony*, to help answer the Original Poster's question, rather than follow that rabbit down into the warren of distraction...)

[ironic —
From Fowler's Dictionary of Modern English Usage](http://www.oxfordreference.com/search?source=%2F10.1093%2Facref%2F9780199661350.001.0001%2Facref-9780199661350&q=ironic)

( a ) using or characterized by irony, i.e. relying for its effect on a contrast between the apparent and the intended meaning of a word, smile, look, laugh, etc.: e.g., *If there was anything ironic in my meaning, it was levelled at your readers, not at you,* —Horace Walpole, 1788

[And from the American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=ironic)

adj.
1. Characterized by or constituting irony.
2. Given to the use of irony.
**3. Poignantly contrary to what was expected or intended: madness, an ironic fate for such a clear thinker.
4. Usage Problem Coincidental or improbable.**

Usage Note: In its nonliterary uses, **irony refers to an incongruity between what is expected and what actually occurs, especially if what actually occurs seems designed to thwart or mock human wishes. For example, in the sentence "Ironically, even as the government was fulminating against American policy, American jeans and videocassettes were the hottest items in the stalls of the market," the incongruity exemplifies human inconsistency.**

The bold type is my emphasis. To me, the element in your sentence of lack of self-awareness precludes irony in the senses I've referenced, because your example shows more than just opposite meaning, incongruity, inconsistency or improbability.